# Trasparent background CurvedNavigationBar

Tags: flutter, dart

how it's possible do transparent background for CurvedNavigationBar?

[image]

This is the code about CurvedNavigationBar :

```
bottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
        onTap: (int index) => setState(() => _currentIndex = index),
        index: _currentIndex,
        buttonBackgroundColor: SVConst.mainColor,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        color: SVConst.mainColor,
        items: <Widget>[
          for (final tabItem in TabNavigationItem.items) tabItem.icon
        ],
      ),
```

This is URL about rep if you would see more:

https://github.com/EliaTolin/StatusVaccini

Thanks.

Comment: Did this link resolve your issue?
https://github.com/rafalbednarczuk/curved_navigation_bar/issues/31

Comment: Check this comment: https://github.com/rafalbednarczuk/curved_navigation_bar/issues/31#issuecomment-672248592

Answer (score 2):

Use this in `Scaffold`

```
extendBody: true,
```

and use this in `CurvedNavigationBar`

```
backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
```

Here is the example

```
return Scaffold(
  ...
  extendBody: true,

  bottomNavigationBar: CurvedNavigationBar(
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    ...
  ),
```

Comment: This works well after removing `SafeArea` widget

Answer (score 1):

This is a common request from many flutter developers, but the plugin still has no support for this. But there is an indirect way to achieve it through `Stack` like this:

```
Scaffold(
    body: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[

        //Place your scaffold body here
        Text('This is the body'),

        Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: CurvedNavigationBar(
             onTap: (int index) => setState(() => _currentIndex = index),
             index: _currentIndex,
             buttonBackgroundColor: SVConst.mainColor,
             backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
             color: SVConst.mainColor,
             items: <Widget>[
              for (final tabItem in TabNavigationItem.items) tabItem.icon
             ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

[This package](https://pub.dev/packages/fluid_bottom_nav_bar) is a good alternative.